# Baseline hazard function is the hazard function obtained when all covariates are set to zero

Tags: r, regression, survival, prediction, cox-model

I am trying to learn Cox proportional hazard model but I have hit a wall with the `basehaz` function.

Lets suppose for example I have some data that I want to use but there is a column such as BMI. The BMI has 3 levels: Underweight, normal weight and fat. How could one of these levels be set to zero?

In addition lets suppose I have a continuous variable such as IQ. Does that mean the model wants to take the base for the IQ to be 0?

Comment: Would it work to use -1, 0 and 1?

Comment: the baseline hazard can be defined at the _mean_ values (i.e. not strictly zero), but your covariates in the equation for the log-partial-hazards will be centered now (i.e. x - mean(x)). Related: See the "centered" param in https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/survival/versions/2.44-1.1/topics/basehaz.

Comment: Actually, and this is important, the `basehaz` by default a: returns the *cumulative* hazard function and b: *centers* all covariates (regardless of whether they were dummy encoded). The main response is right: if you set `centered=F` as an option to `basehaz`, then you will get the BL hazard function for the referent group. It is also related to the survival by $\exp(-\Lambda(t))$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) There are different ways to include categorical variables into the analysis. The most popular and default in most packages is so called 
*dummy coding* where the first category is the "reference" category and the other are code 1 if the observation is from the category and 0 otherwise. Below is an example with R where "a" is the reference category and the columns `x1b` and `x1c` would enter the analysis. The coefficients for these variables would than indicate differences compared to category "a".

```r
# create example data set
df <- data.frame(x1 = sample(letters[1:3], 6, replace = TRUE))
df
#>   x1
#> 1  b
#> 2  c
#> 3  a
#> 4  b
#> 5  a
#> 6  c
# dummy coding
cbind(df, model.matrix(~x1, df)[,-1])
#>   x1 x1b x1c
#> 1  b   1   0
#> 2  c   0   1
#> 3  a   0   0
#> 4  b   1   0
#> 5  a   0   0
#> 6  c   0   1
```

2) For the baseline hazard continuous variables have to be set to 0 as you suspect, which is why the baseline hazard often does not have a useful interpretation and not the focus of the analysis. What is done sometimes is to center the continuous variable. That way the baseline hazard corresponds to the mean value.

<sup>Created on 2019-06-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Note that the details can depend on the software package used for the survival analysis. For example, SAS uses the last named level of a categorical variable as the reference, unlike R; see the end of [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/26540/28500) for example. Also if you use the `basehaz()` function in R at default settings the result is provided for a situation with all predictors at their average values across the dataset. This makes no sense for categorical predictors, as the [authors themselves note](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/survival.pdf).